# extract word from string usinfg regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex-greedy, regexp-replace

> accusantique et o (MLS® R2608327). Sed ut perspiciatis voluptatem mls
> listing :MLS&reg#:12243235435 beatae vitae dicta MLS Number#:12243235435 sunt
> 3543654654675645654654 explicabo .

Given the string above how could I extract "(MLS® R2608327)"or"MLS&reg#:12243235435"or"MLS Number#:12243235435" in the string? value of it might change as this is dynamic. So, other instance might be "135435". The location/sequence might also change, it could be in the middle or last part.

This regex

> ^ *((MLS|mls|Mls|MLS&reg|mls&reg|Mls&reg|MLS®|MLS® Number|mls
> Number|Mls Number|mls®|Mls®|Property
> ID|)[^A-Za-z0-9]*)?(([^?*/\:;<> ]{1,23}\d{2,23}[^?*/\:;<>
> ]{1,23}) *)$

This regex is working well but it is not extracting mls:#w3432423 from a string like dfnjkgfkhgb mls:#234234245 fgjhfgf 3498234789 dshfdsfgbjhsf.

Comment: See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/4642212) and the [regex tag wiki](/tags/regex/info) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](//regex101.com/).

Comment: If you omit the anchors, the pattern seems to match `mls:#w3432423` from `dfnjkgfkhgb mls:#234234245 fgjhfgf 3498234789 dshfdsfgbjhsf.` Perhaps you could shorten the pattern a bit and  use a case insensitive flag `/i` see https://regex101.com/r/VAvfcg/1 Note that in the example string, you get multiple matches with group 1 and group 2 which you could get for example using [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Thankyou so much @Thefourthbird it works perfectly. but it is also picking up numbers, like it is picking up "3498234789" also. is there any way to put a condition in this regex that it only matches the string that starts with these three characters "MLS"

Comment: @TestID Do you mean like this? `\b((?:MLS(?:&reg|®?(?: Number)?))[^A-Za-z0-9]*)([^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23}\d{2,23}[^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23})` https://regex101.com/r/c2Y8OV/1

Answer (score 0):

Using a case insentive match, you can use:

```
\b(MLS(?:&reg|®?(?: Number)?)[^A-Za-z0-9]*)([^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23}\d{2,23}[^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23})
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `MLS` Match literally
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `&reg` Match literally
    - `|` Or
    - `®?(?: Number)?` Match optional ® and optional  `Number`
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `[^A-Za-z0-9]*` Match optional chars other then the listed
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23}` Match 1-23 repetitions of any char except the listed
  - `\d{2,23}` Match 2 -23 digits
  - `[^?*\/\\:;<> ]{1,23}` Match 1-23 repetitions of any char except the listed
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b7MQBa/1)